# Why doesn't this print the last character of the word?

Tags: java, char, string-length

I'm using java. I'm trying pull out the last letter of a word of 8 characters or less. Then pulling out each character after

```
    lengthOfWord = word.length();
    lc = word.charAt(lengthOfWord -1);

    if (lengthOfWord == 1)
        System.out.println(lc);
```

When I try to use a word with one character, it says "String index out of range: -1" and when I try using a word of two characters, it says build successfully, but doesn't print anything.

Comment: Please also include what happened.  I suspect that it didn't silently fail, and that the error message includes a hint as to the problem...

Answer (score 1):

`lengthOfWord` is past the bounds of `word`.  Use:

```
lc = word.charAt(lengthOfWord - 1);
```

Remember that .length() returns the number of characters of an object, but the index of an object starts at `0` and ends at `length()-1`.

**UPDATE**
Try this to check all characters in the word:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
  System.out.println("Char " + i + ": " + word.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: Well I tried this, and I no longer get an error, but my program prints nothing. It just says build is successful. I edited my question to show what I've tried.

Comment: Is it possible that `word` has a blank character at the end of it?

Comment: Try the update to my answer.  If you get a blank character anywhere there shouldn't be, there's an issue somewhere else in the code.  If the print-out goes to 5 characters but there are only 4 in the word, there's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

lengthOfWord is 0 based, so you might wanna try lc = word.charAt(lengthOfWord - 1);